# How do I merge two variables in R, if one is nested?

Tags: r, variables

Here are my results after defining the variables and doing a tally:

```html
Var 1:
0     1     <NA>
1056  542   3300 


Var 2:
0     1     <NA>
710   52     4136


The desired variable should be:

Var 3
0      1     <NA>
1766  594    2538
```

Essentially:

- The "0" or "False" for Var 3, should be a sum of the "0" counts for Vars 1 and 2.
- The "1" or "True" for Var 3, should be a sum of the "1" counts for Vars 1 and 2.
- The NAs for Var 3 should be the difference between Vars' 1 and 2 NAs.

I'm using survey data, and simply summing the variables after they are defined won't give me the result.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a quick and dirty solution, but it is still quite robust.

```
var1 <- c(  "0"=1056,  "1"=542,   "<NA>"=3300 )
var2 <- c(  "0"=710,  "1"=52,   "<NA>"=4136 )


bind_rows(var1, var2) %>% colSums()
```

Comment: What is need is for my new variable (Var 3) to have 1766 zeros, 594 ones, and 2538 NAs. Then after doing a tally, the result should look like what I have in the code block. But, thanks for your help @c0bra